# How to get Java Script element value in NSString ? (iphone)

Tags: javascript, iphone, nsstring, element

I have this much javascript

```
   <p>
   <label style="top:16px" for="<%= ClientName.ClientID %>">Client Name</label>
   <so:BoundSOTextBox autocomplete="off" runat="server" CssClass="stack radius" ID="ClientName" Width="98%" />
   </p>
```

Now I want to get ClientName.ClientID element name in the string

So I am using ...

```
NSString *retStr = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"ClientName\");"];
```

I am using this code in `webViewDidFinishLoad` method

but i am not able to get it ...

Can anyone tell me what to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById(\"Client Name\")` should be `document.getElementById(\"ClientName\")` since you specified `ID="ClientName"`

I'm not sure what `<so:BoundSOTextBox>` renders as HTML but I don't think the DOM element supports `.ClientName.ClientID`. Anway as I said I don't know what it renders exactly.

**update**

to get the input's value you should use `document.getElementById(\"ClientName\").value` if the rendered component is a `<div> or <span> etc.` you want need to use `innerHTML` instead of `value`. `document.getElementById(\"ClientName\").innerHTML`

Comment: Manuel .. I have changed it .. as you said and also edited in the question above .. but still it is not getting anything ..

Comment: is it a `<input type='text'>` or something? then you probably want to change it to `document.getElementById(\"ClientName\").value`

Comment: did it ,.. but ur answer helped a lot :D